# Jquery.Cycle not running on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm running a jquery.cycle gallery using nested cycles according to [this example.](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/nest.html) The problem I'm having is that the cycle that's visible on page load doesn't start running automatically. In order to get it to run I have to navigate to the second gallery, then click back to the first. Even then, the gallery stops running after only one image even though there are several images in the set.

Any suggestions? I'm on a deadline for this thing, but after staring at it for days I'm stuck.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                    var gLength = $('#hovergal > ul').size();
                    if( gLength > 1)
                        {
                            //move over gallery to allow room for nav
                            $('#hovergal').css("marginLeft","100px");

                        //stop subgal initially
                            $('#hovergal .subgal').cycle({
                                fx: 'fade',
                                timeout: 10000,
                                slideExpr: 'li'
                            }).cycle('pause');

                            //start subgal on click
                            $('#hovergal').cycle({
                                fx: 'scrollUp',
                                speed: 300,
                                timeout: 0,
                                slideExpr: '>ul.subgal',
                                pager: 1,
                                pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i) {
                                    return $('aside.sgnav a:eq(' + i + ')');
                                },
                                after: function(curr,next,opts) {
                                    var cmd = opts.currSlide == 1 ? 'resume' : 'pause';
                                    $('ul.subgal').cycle(cmd);
                                }
                            });
                    } else {//else, if there's only one gallery to be shown

                        $('#hovergal .subgal').cycle({
                            fx: 'fade',
                            timeout: 3000,
                            slideExpr: 'li',

                        }); 
                    };

                    $('.sgcaption').each(function() {
                            if ($(this).contents().length == 0){
                                $(this).hide();
                            }
                        });

            });
        </script>


 <div id="hovergal">

<ul class="subgal">

 <li><a href="Quality Printers features the work of the ArtFuse Collective."><img src="http://localhost/qp/images/83.jpg" rel="http://localhost/qp/images/83t.jpg" title="Quality Printers features the work of the ArtFuse Collective." /></a>

<span class="sgcaption">Quality Printers features the work of the ArtFuse Collective.</span></li>


 <li><a href="Quality Printers features the work of the ArtFuse Collective."><img src="http://localhost/qp/images/84.jpg" rel="http://localhost/qp/images/84t.jpg" title="Quality Printers features the work of the ArtFuse Collective." /></a>

<span class="sgcaption">Quality Printers features the work of the ArtFuse Collective.</span></li>
</ul>

<ul class="subgal">
 <li><a href="Events hosted at Quality Printers have attracted upward of 70 attendees."><img src="http://localhost/qp/images/78.jpg" rel="http://localhost/qp/images/78t.jpg" title="Events hosted at Quality Printers have attracted upward of 70 attendees." /></a>

<span class="sgcaption">Events hosted at Quality Printers have attracted upward of 70 attendees.</span></li>


 <li><a href="We the Gentlemen Performs in our Creative Cultural Center"><img src="http://localhost/qp/images/79.jpg" rel="http://localhost/qp/images/79t.jpg" title="We the Gentlemen Performs in our Creative Cultural Center" /></a>

<span class="sgcaption">We the Gentlemen Performs in our Creative Cultural Center</span></li>


 <li><a href="We the Gentlemen Performs in our Creative Cultural Center"><img src="http://localhost/qp/images/80.jpg" rel="http://localhost/qp/images/80t.jpg" title="We the Gentlemen Performs in our Creative Cultural Center" /></a>

<span class="sgcaption">We the Gentlemen Performs in our Creative Cultural Center</span></li>


 <li><a href="Events hosted at Quality Printers have attracted upward of 70 attendees."><img src="http://localhost/qp/images/81.jpg" rel="http://localhost/qp/images/81t.jpg" title="Events hosted at Quality Printers have attracted upward of 70 attendees." /></a>
<span class="sgcaption">Events hosted at Quality Printers have attracted upward of 70 attendees.</span></li>    </ul>
 </div>

 <aside class="sgnav right">
<a class="rounded" href="#">Current</a>
<a class="rounded" href="#">Past</a>
</aside>
```

**EDIT** Solved it! I realized the problem was that the script was set up specifically so that all galleries were stopped on page load. After looking through the Jquery.Cycle options, I came up with this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                    var gLength = $('#hovergal > ul').size();
                    if( gLength > 1)
                        {
                            //move over gallery to allow room for nav
                            $('#hovergal').css("marginLeft","100px");

                        //stop subgal initially
                            $('#hovergal .subgal').cycle({
                                fx: 'fade',
                                timeout: 10000,
                                slideExpr: 'li'
                            }).cycle();

                            //start subgal on click
                            $('#hovergal').cycle({
                                fx: 'scrollUp',
                                speed: 300,
                                timeout: 0,
                                slideExpr: '>ul.subgal',
                                pager: 1,
                                pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i) {
                                    return $('aside.sgnav a:eq(' + i + ')');
                                },
                                before: function(curr,next,opts) {
                                    $('ul.subgal').cycle({startingSlide:0});
                                }
                            });
                    } else {//else, if there's only one gallery to be shown

                        $('#hovergal .subgal').cycle({
                            fx: 'fade',
                            timeout: 3000,
                            slideExpr: 'li',

                        }); 
                    };

                    $('.sgcaption').each(function() {
                            if ($(this).contents().length == 0){
                                $(this).hide();
                            }
                        });

            });
```

This script starts all galleries on page load, and when a new gallery is selected via the pager the chosen gallery resets to its first slide. There's probably a more elegant way of handling this, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Both your `<ul>` elements are being ended before their last list items:

```
</ul>
<span class="sgcaption">Quality Printers features the work of the ArtFuse Collective.</span></li>
```

---

This makes it work.  The example only had one cycle nested in the main cycle so it checked `opts.currSlide` to see if it was active.  It would pause when it switched to 0 or 2, but resume when the currSlide was 1.  When you changed to the second cycle in your code, it would start, but when you changed back, it would only show you the remainder of its current animation before pausing again.

```
after: function(curr, next, opts) {
    $(curr).cycle("pause");
    $(next).cycle("resume");
}
```

Comment: Fixed; it didn't make a difference in terms of the plugin failing to run on page load, though.

Comment: Thanks! This did in fact solve the problem of the animation failing to continue after I clicked back to it, but I still had the issue of the cycle not running when the page loaded. After thinking about it for a bit I came up with a solution that you can see in my edited initial question. It works, but I don't know if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: You don't need to call `cycle()` after the instantiation.  Your before function is good, as it restarts the nested one when you change but your other cycles will still be running, despite the fact that they are hidden.  It isn't a big deal, since the end user won't notice, unless you have bunch.

Comment: There are only three cycles on each page, including the one that navigates between the two sub cycles, so I don't think it will be a huge performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you have to do the following to make the subcycles begin on load:

Remove the 'pause' command from your sub-cycle instantiation calls.

```
$('#hovergal .subgal').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 10000,
    slideExpr: 'li'
});    // removed .cycle('pause')
```

Remove the 'after' callback function. It is pausing your sub-cycles. Your new main cycle call should look like this:

```
$('#hovergal').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollUp',
    speed: 300,
    timeout: 0,
    slideExpr: '>ul.subgal',
    pager: 1,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function (i) {
        return $('aside.sgnav a:eq(' + i + ')');
    }
});
```

Also, your HTML is not valid markup. You may want to spend some time cleaning it up.

Comment: How is it invalid? If you mean the href element, I know about that already; I just have to change a line in my CMS's script to get rid of it.